# Environment check error in Stable Baselines 3 when using marlenv and gymnasium

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning

**marlenv.py**

```
import gymnasium as gym
from gymnasium.spaces import Discrete, Box, Dict
from stable_baselines3.common.env_checker import check_env
import numpy as np

from pprint import pprint

class MyMultiAgentEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super(MyMultiAgentEnv, self).__init__()

        self.config = config
...
    def reset(self, *, seed=None, options=None):
      ...
...
    def step(self, action_dict):
      ...
...
```

When I run  `check_env()` on the class, I get the infamous **AssertionError: Your environment must inherit from the gymnasium.Env class cf. https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/env/**. Here's how I'm doing check_env():

**train.py**

```
from marlenv import MyMultiAgentEnv
import gymnasium as gym
from gymnasium.envs.registration import register

from stable_baselines3.common.env_util import make_vec_env
from stable_baselines3.common.env_checker import check_env
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import VecNormalize

register(
    id="marlenv-v0",
    entry_point="marlenv:MyMultiAgentEnv",
)
env = gym.make('marlenv-v0', config=exp_config)
env = make_vec_env(lambda: env)
env = VecNormalize(env)

check_env(env, warn=True)
```

This is the information on **versions**:

**Python 3.11.5** (Through Anaconda)

**gymnasium 0.29.1**

**SB3 2.2.1**

Most of the answers online say that you have to import gymnasium and not gym, which is something I have done here. Please advise/guide me on how I could proceed!